# Get "XOR Mask" and "AND mask" from Icon

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, awt

I need to get the `XOR Mask` and the `AND Mask` from an Icon(`.ICO`) file.

If anyone can suggest a way how I can do this from Java, this would be brilliant.
If not, do you know of any application which can get these two masks and allow you
to dump them?

Comment: Have you referred to the Wikipedia page for the .ICO file format? It gives a pretty thorough description of the .ICO file format, enough to make it fairly straightforward to write a simple Java file parsing loop that can find and extract the portions of the file that you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The wikipedia article on Windows Icon Image File format, https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICO_(file_format), is very straight forward.

There are three sections, header, entries, and image data. The header is 6 bytes. each entry is 16 bytes. Offset 8 of of each entry structure is a Java integer for the offset to the image data

The image data of  32 bitDepth bitmap has no AND mask. If it is a 24 bitDepth then it needs XOR color mask and 1 bitDepth AND mask.

```
bytes[] openFile(String fname) throws Exception
{
 java.io.InputStream file = new java.io.FileInputStream(fname);
 bytes []bytes = new bytes[file.available()];
 file.read(bytes);
 file.close();
 return bytes;
}

//assumes 24 bitDepth
bytes[] getXorMask(bytes []ico)
{
 int i = 6 + 8;
 i = bytes[i+0] | (bytes[i+1]<<1) | (bytes[i+2]<<2) | (bytes[i+3]<<3);
 i += sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); // WOW! NOT JAVA
 
 int width = bytes[6] == 0 ? 256 : bytes[6];
 int height = bytes[7] == 0 ? 256 : bytes[7];
 int sz = width * height * 3; // very presumptious
 byte []bytes = new byte[sz];

 for(int e=0; e<sz; ) bytes[e++] = ico[i++];

 return bytes;
}

bytes[] getAndMask(bytes []ico)
{
 int i = 6 + 8;
 i = bytes[i+0] | (bytes[i+1]<<1) | (bytes[i+2]<<2) | (bytes[i+3]<<3);
 i += sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER); // WOW! NOT JAVA
 
 int width = bytes[6] == 0 ? 256 : bytes[6];
 int height = bytes[7] == 0 ? 256 : bytes[7];
 int sz = width * height * 3; // very presumptious
 byte []bytes = new byte[sz];

 i += sz; // seek to monochrome mask

 // only works if bounds is multiple of 4
 sz = width/8 * height;
 for(int e=0; e<sz; ) bytes[e++] = ico[i++];

 return bytes;
}
```

The preceding example always gets the first image entry. Also I thought this was simple implementation but Java knows nothing about BITMAPINFOHEADER and this structure is a variable size structure.

Edit:

Firstly big ups to Raymond Chen. He has a course on Icons (part 1 - part 4) on MSDN.

Further reading at, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms997538(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN, shows that the BITMAPINFOHEADER structure should be of fixed size. Check out win32 definition of struct BITMAPINFOHEADER. Size of it is 40 bytes.

Edit:
BITMAPINFOHEADER structure's first DWORD is the size of the structure in little endian.